# How to copy entire project to another path in server using POST-RECEIVE hook in git?

Tags: git, github, githooks

I want to move entire project to another location in git remote server.

For example, if I have project called 'sample-project' in git server, I want it to copy the entire project to

> /home/username/projects/

location. With my search I found that '**rsync**' can be used for it.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the remote a `bare` repository? Do you want your copy to be a `bare`?

Comment: Really i'm not sure about bare repository. Installed Gitlab-ce edition.
And i want the copy as just normal file system. Not as another repo.

Comment: I'd just clone the repository locally, checkout the branch I'm interested in and on post-receive let the clone call `git pull`

Comment: In case, if we create a new project using web console. Can we copy this new project automatically? And also can it be up-to-date after each check-in or push to repo?

Comment: I don't know if gitlab provides something like this, but I doubt it. Usually, thats a job for a CI/CD (Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery) service, not a git-hosting-service.

Comment: Thanks @tkausl, i will try with puppet to do this job.